# Create SQL query for the given dataset

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below dataset available.

[image]

I want to get below result.

[image]

I am trying to get the results using windowing functions, but am not able to find a way to do it.
Can someone please help.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number()` to generate a sequence and subtract from `value`.  That is a constant for the groups you want:

```
select element, min(value), max(value)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by element order by value) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by element, (value - seqnum)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man..That gave me the required results.!!! :)

Comment: This will also give the same results:




select ele, minval, maxval from
(select ele, minval, maxval, row_number() over (partition by ele order by ele) as row from
(select ele, min(val) over (partition by ele order by ele) as minval, max(val) over (partition by ele order by ele) as maxval
from df order by ele)q)q2
where row = 1